# Manually entering contingency table in R

Tags: r, contingency

Hi I have the following code in R,

```
> trial <- matrix(c(6,9,6,5,2,2,5,8,5,3,2,4,6,8,8), ncol=5,byrow=T)
> colnames(trial) <- c('Never','Rarely','Sometimes', 'Often' ,'Always')
> rownames(trial) <- c('Walk', 'Bus','Drive')

> trial
      Never Rarely Sometimes Often Always
Walk      6      9         6     5      2
Bus       2      5         8     5      3
Drive     2      4         6     8      8
```

However what I want is;

```
Breakfast  Never  Rarely  Sometimes Often  Always
Travel
Walk         6      9       6         5      2
Bus          2      5       8         5      3
Drive        2      4       6         8      8
```

i.e. a contingency table where Breakfast has options Never, Rarely etc.
and Travel has options Walk,bus etc. 
Thank you

Comment: Care to share an explanation?

Comment: I also don't really understand the question. Do you want the words "Breakfast" and "Travel" to explicitly appear in the printed matrix? Because other than that the two are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered courtesy: Salvatore S. Mangiafico, Ph.D.

```
trial <- matrix(c(6,9,6,5,2,2,5,8,5,3,2,4,6,8,8), ncol=5,byrow=T)
colnames(trial) <- c('Never','Rarely','Sometimes', 'Often' ,'Always')
rownames(trial) <- c('Walk', 'Bus','Drive')

Trial = as.table(trial)

dimnames(Trial)
names(dimnames(Trial)) = c("Transport", "Breakfast")
```